# Magento m1 to m2 ce-to-ce Data migration issues

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-2.1, migration, magento2-migration-tool

We are trying to Migrate `Magento 1.7.x to 2.1.x` data migration using the [Magento Data Migration Tools](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool.html) Script.

below errors are display,

> [2017-09-06 14:00:03][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step:
>   EAV Step]: started
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:03][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step:
>   Customer Attributes Step]: started
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:03][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step:
>   Map Step]: started
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:06][ERROR]: Source documents are not mapped:
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:06][ERROR]: Source documents are not mapped:
>   addtocart_device,addtowishlist_device,banners,banners_store,bannerslider,core_directory_storage,ebizmarts_ecomm360,ebizmarts_mailchimppro,elasticemail_transaction,gtspeed_image,gtspeed_stat,ibanners_banner,ibanners_group,interaktingslider_slide,interaktingslider_slide_position,interaktingslider_slide_store,m_attribute,m_db,m_db_log,m_edit_session,m_filter,m_filter2,m_filter2_store,m_filter2_value,m_filter2_value_store,m_filter_datetime,m_filter_decimal,m_filter_int,m_filter_text,m_filter_varchar,magazento_socialgp,magebuzz_testimonial,magenotification,magenotification_extension_feedback,magenotification_extension_feedbackmessage,magenotification_log,mobicommerce_applications2,mobicommerce_applications_settings2,mobicommerce_category_icon2,mobicommerce_category_widget2,mobicommerce_devicetokens,mobicommerce_licence,mobicommerce_notification,mobicommerce_widget2,mobistorelocator_holiday2,mobistorelocator_image2,mobistorelocator_location2,mobistorelocator_rating2,mobistorelocator_specialday2,mobistorelocator_store2,mobistorelocator_store_value2,mobistorelocator_storereviews2,neotheme_blog_category,neotheme_blog_comment,neotheme_blog_post,neotheme_blog_tag,payucheckout_api_debug,plumbase_product,pricecalculator,pricecheck,pws_productqa,qaz_qbanner,qaz_qbanner_category,qaz_qbanner_image,qaz_qbanner_page,qaz_qbanner_store,slide,snippet,themeswitcher_theme,themeswitcher_theme_browser,themeswitcher_theme_platform,twlogin_customer2,web,widgento_login
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:06][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document:
>   catalog_product_option. Fields: regex,regex_message,validators
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:06][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document:
>   catalogrule. Fields: attribute_to_select
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:06][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document:
>   catalogrule_product. Fields: attribute_to_select
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:06][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document:
>   sales_flat_order. Fields:
>   onestepcheckout_customercomment,orderfromplatform
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:06][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document:
>   sales_flat_order_item. Fields:
>   frame_img1,frame_img2,frame_img3,frame_img4
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of data types. Source
>   document: catalogrule_product. Fields: action_operator
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:06][WARNING]: Mismatch of data types. Destination
>   document: catalogrule_product. Fields: action_operator [2017-09-06
>   14:00:06][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite
>   Step]: started
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:06][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step:
>   Log Step]: started
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:06][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step:
>   Ratings Step]: started
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:06][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step:
>   ConfigurablePrices step]: started
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:06][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step:
>   OrderGrids Step]: started
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:06][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step:
>   Tier Price Step]: started
>
> [2017-09-06 14:00:06][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step:
>   SalesIncrement Step]: started

`[Migration\Exception]` Integrity check failed

**We are getting this errors, while run the `config.xml` file. Anyone please review the issues and let me know your suggestions to fixes the issues**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your errors are self explanatory. Did you read the migration documentation?

I'll try to guide you in the right direction:

As you can see, your old M1 Database contains a lot of extra tables or fields for custom modules. For example:

- ebizmarts_mailchimppro
- interaktingslider_slide
- mobicommerce
- twlogin

to mention a few.

Now, from the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-troubleshooting.html):

```
Some Magento 1 entities (in most cases, coming from extensions) 
do not exist in the Magento 2 database.

This message appears because the Data Migration Tool runs internal 
tests to verify that tables and fields are consistent between 
source (Magento 1) and destination (Magento 2) databases.
```

So you either install the M2 versions of the modules, or you tell the migration tool to ignore all the unmapped documents or fields by editing your map.xml file. Read the documentation as to where to configure which map file is used for your magento 1 version.

Then ignore all the fields and tables, for example:

```
<ignore>
  <document>addtocart_device</document>
</ignore>
```

and

```
<ignore>
   <field>catalogrule.attribute_to_select</field>
</ignore>
```

If tables or fields are called differently in M2, you can rename tables or move fields by using eg:

```
<rename>
  <document>sales_flat_quote_item</document>
  <to>quote_item</to>
</rename>
```

and

```
<move>
  <field>catalog_category_entity_varchar.entity_id</field>
  <to>catalog_category_entity_varchar.row_id</to>
</move>
```

respectively.

--- edit as per comment:

*Example error:*

```
[2017-09-06 14:00:06][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_order. Fields: onestepcheckout_customercomment,orderfromplatform
```

*Fix:*

```
<ignore>
   <field>sales_flat_order.onestepcheckout_customercomment</field>
</ignore>
<ignore>
   <field>sales_flat_order.orderfromplatform</field>
</ignore>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. below are the recent migration error logs kindly check that and let us know ur suggestion.

> [2017-09-07 07:29:04][ERROR]: Destination documents are not mapped: sales_flat_order
.........
> [2017-09-07 07:29:04][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started

Comment: @UDHAYAKUMAR I've given you the answer. Edit your map.xml file and try to add one document (table) to be ignored and you will see it disappear from your error log when trying to migrate again. Work through it until none are 'unmapped'.

Comment: i followed in your comment ignored sales_flat_order and again run the command below error to be display,

[2017-09-07 07:44:25][ERROR]: Document has ambiguous configuration: sales_flat_order

Comment: @UDHAYAKUMAR: Please update your post with the exact lines you put into your map.xml file. I will briefly updated my answer with the example of how to ignore the 2 fields in the sales_flat_order table - you can't ignore the full table as you need it.

Comment: <ignore>
                <document>sales_flat_order</document>           
 </ignore> - this is wat we added in map.xml. Kindly let me know ur suggestion.

Comment: Please see the end of my answer above, i've addressed that error. You can't ignore the complete sales_flat_order table, you need it. Also, the error says you have 2 fields in that table `Fields: onestepcheckout_customercomment,orderfromplatform` that can not be mapped (as they come from modules). So ignore those.

Comment: We are already ignored and now its displaying error log 

[2017-09-07 09:58:48][ERROR]: Document has ambiguous configuration: sales_flat_order

Comment: If you ignore it you will lose all past orders. As i said, you need that table, it exists in magento2, just 2 fields are not mapped. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-troubleshooting.html

Comment: [2017-09-07 10:03:39][ERROR]: Destination documents are not mapped: sales_flat_order


We removed ignored sales_flat_order table,

Now we are getting above error..

Comment: Your map.xml file [from the version folder of your m1 version] should already have certain rules defined. such as as rename for `sales_flat_order` to `sales_order`. I'd always restart the migration from a fresh version of the m1 database.

Comment: In magento2  default db not found  sales_flat_order  table , 

How to handle below erroe ,

[2017-09-07 10:27:17][ERROR]: Destination documents are not mapped: sales_flat_order

Comment: See the above comment

Comment: You mean fresh m1 database or existing m1 database .

Comment: Existing. Sorry it's been a while since I last did a migrate. Are you using the correct map file for your M1 version?

Comment: yes , i am using correct map file for m1 version.

Comment: We have followed as per your suggestion we have successfully migrated magento1.7.x to magento2.1.6...
Thanks for your valuable support.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the missing table in map.xml

```
    <ignore>
        <field>email_abandoned_cart</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>temando_collection_point_search</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>temando_order_collection_point</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>temando_quote_collection_point</field>
    </ignore>
```

and Run

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings --**reset** /var/www/html/YOUR_ROOT_PATH/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.4/config.xml
```

after not complete so run ----------------------------(auto)

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings --**auto** /var/www/html/YOUR_ROOT_PATH/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.4/config.xml
```